# Import collection of modules in python

Tags: python

I trying to import a package that I had created and when i tried to import it,

the following output is shown:
  (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1')

in each folder in my package (`__init__.py`) has been created.

the package is in the following path
(/Users/user/Desktop/package/folder1/test.py)

python is in the following path(/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6'

how can I import the package? do I need to change package's location?

thank you for help

Comment: Are you running `python` in the same directory as the package?

Comment: I'm using Atom as an editor and I'm not sure if they are in the same directory by default or I need to change configuration.  I didn't used to use Atom.

Comment: it doesn't matter what editor you use. just make sure that when you run `python` you're in the `package` folder if you want to import `folder1`. Otherwise you should do what lapinkoira says.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your package to the python path:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you import a python module using `import` python interpreter searches in current directory & paths set in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.
so inorder to work what you are expecting either you should be running the script insider the parent directory or you must include in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to you folder path.

Comment: Using PYTHONPATH may create unwanted issues if several versions of python are installed simultaneously. A more robust way is to create a `usercustomize.py` file as described in the `site` module's documentation. `sys.path` can be manipulated in this file.